# Can I construct a coproduct of a Cartesian product?

Tags: category-theory

In the page 18 of "[Category Theory Lecture Notes](http://www.dcs.ed.ac.uk/home/dt/CT/categories.pdf)" in a remark, Turi says:

> A coproduct puts objects together while keeping them distinct ...

I get confused when it comes to the role of injections in shaping a coproduct. In particular, let's assume two objects $A$ and $B$. Given their Cartesian product $A \times B$, I'd like to first extract $A$ and $B$ via projections, then apply some compositional operations to them, and finally puts them together. To do so, here is what I have imagined:

[image]

However, I can't understand how those injections work to "put objects together". To be specific, the diagram apparently commutes, so both the lower and the upper compositions need to yield the disjoint union. But, how is that possible to have, for example, something like $i_{A} \circ f_{A} \circ \pi_{A} (A\times B) = A' + B'$? I mean the upper path only accesses $A$ and its predecessors, so where does that $B'$ come from? I guess my ambiguity may partially stem from the fact that I have no clue about what an injection mapping could be.

Comment: I don't understand why you talk about injections, since nobody seems to have mentioned those. I'm also confused as to the context of your diagram and what you're trying to do. The equation you write doesn't make sense, how should a composition of arrows yield an object? Also, that diagram does certainly not commute in general.

Comment: @Thorgott: Thanks for your comment. (i) The notion of injection is noted in various texts of category theory, e.g., the same page of the reference above or the Simmon's book on the page 50. So, I don't understand what you mean by nobody has mentioned them. (ii) This is a diagram related to my research. Furthermore, I have passed an object to those compositions, i.e., $A \times B$, and the result is an object, if you note. (iii) Again, the commutativity comes from the context of my research problem. However, it is not the main point of this question.

Comment: In the typical categories you might be working with, a diagram of the form you have written down will virtually never commute (basically, it can only commute in very degenerate cases).  It sounds like you have some very severe misunderstandings though it's hard for me to tell exactly what they are.

Comment: @EricWofsey: Let's ignore the `h` morphism. The remainder of the diagram is just a combination of a pair of projections and a pair of injections. So, I am basically interested in knowing how injections work in coproducts.

Comment: In the category of sets (or relational structures, topological spaces, graphs, etc) coproduct is simply *disjoint union* and the inclusion maps are the inclusions. For groups, coproduct is free product and it also comes with canonical embeddings.

Comment: @User Still, this diagram won't commute for most of the standard examples. The coproduct should be thought of the minimal object for which there exist natural injections from the two objects into the coproduct.

Comment: (i) Ok, I hadn't checked the reference. Peculiar choice of terminology. (ii) A morphism does not take objects to objects, it's a formal arrow between objects. The notion that a "composition yields a disjoint union" does not make sense. (iii) As everybody has pointed out by now, the diagram does not commute in many cases. Saying it's your research problem does not help the people on this site contextualize it. If that's not the main point of your question, what is?